# How to make my webpage divided?

Tags: html

How do I make my HTML Page into tiles? I am trying to add videos through out the webpage, But I want them in rectangle style. I've attached a example:

[image]

Comment: I cannot see the example, edit your question and attach it again

Answer (score 1):

You can use a frameworks like bootstrap to build a Grid layout that will contain the thumbnails in a responsive way.

Anyway, let me suggest http://materializecss.com
I'm using the cards design pattern to show video thumbnails, and it's neat and amazing, have a look:
[materializecss cards](http://materializecss.com/cards.html)